# Upgrading mobile processor, socket confusion

Tags: laptop, cpu, sockets, processor-socket

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_G1

I have a Socket 989 rPGA (I think, Dell Inspiron D7010).

I have 3 questions that I could use some help with.

1. According to wikipedia, with Socket 989 rPGA can I use either G1 or G2 socket processors?
2. Can I also upgrade to an Ivy Bridge mobile processor when they start to retail?
3. How can I make absolutely sure what socket my laptop's motherboard is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- According to Wikipedia...

> there are Socket G/rPGA 989 sockets that can take Socket G1/rPGA 988A or Socket G2/rPGA 988B packaged processors

... so not all Socket G can use either.  Getting the exact specifications from Dell based on your service tag would be the way to find out which yours has and can use.

- You cannot currently upgrade to an Ivy Bridge processor.  First, your BIOS must be written to recognize the processor you put in the socket... and as they have not been released yet, your BIOS will not recognize one if you put it in.  To anticipate your possible next question based on this, I have no idea if Dell plans on releasing an updated BIOS that would recognize an Ivy Bridge, but I can make an educated guess.  No, they will not.  Why not?  Because Dell is in the business to sell laptops.  They will not sell laptops if you upgrade your existing one.  This is the model that they and just about every other laptop manufacturer follows.  It is a different model from the one that Desktop motherboard manufacturers use.  In almost every case (with the exception of some of the custom laptop manufacturers) when a laptop is released, the processors it supports are based on what that company intended to sell with that equipment AT THAT TIME.  Future BIOS releases are only to fix issues, not add more processor support.  Generally speaking.
- Examine the specifications at support.dell.com for your exact model.  If that information is not detailed there, pull your laptop apart and examine exactly which processor you have.

Answer (score 0):

Sandy Bridge is Gen2, Ivy Bridge is Gen3. Your mainboard will not support it.